# Buttons in bootstrap modal is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have a modal as navigation bar for mobile view, And

When I run the below snippet, In **mobile view** when I click on icon bar/ menu bar, None of buttons are responding in the modal. I am not getting any clue on this. Thanks for any help in advance

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="height: 100vh !important">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 100vh; opacity:1">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  >&times;</button>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md" >
                  <li><a href="#myPage">HOME1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#band">BAND1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tour">TOUR1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  <div class="bg-img-hero">
     <nav class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myModal">
              <span class="icon-bar" style="color: yellow !important"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
              </button>

           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                 <li ><a href="HowItWorks.html" style="color: white !important">HOME</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#band" style="color: white !important">BAND</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#tour" style="color: white !important">TOUR</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contact" style="color: white !important">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md" >
                 <li><a href="HowItWorks.html">HOME1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#band">BAND1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#tour">TOUR1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>

        </div>
     </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a working fiddle for this. It will be helpful to debug and check the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add All JS & CSS file

also change here `data-toggle="collapse"` to `data-toggle="modal"`

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
              <span class="icon-bar" style="color: yellow !important"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
              </button>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="height: 100vh !important">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 100vh; opacity:1">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  >&times;</button>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md" >
                  <li><a href="#myPage">HOME1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#band">BAND1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tour">TOUR1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  <div class="bg-img-hero">
     <nav class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
              <span class="icon-bar" style="color: yellow !important"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
              </button>
              <img src="Images\logos\flexit-logo-TM-comp.png" style="padding-top:15px" >  
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                 <li ><a href="HowItWorks.html" style="color: white !important">HOME</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#band" style="color: white !important">BAND</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#tour" style="color: white !important">TOUR</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contact" style="color: white !important">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md" >
                 <li><a href="HowItWorks.html">HOME1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#band">BAND1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#tour">TOUR1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>

        </div>
     </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was bothering me for last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

please check your bootstrap version and the relevant jquery version. try adding cdns in to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

when those links are not added collapse will not works fine.